Scrolling on a embedded element in HTML
I am attempting to scroll an embedded element but not scroll the HTML body. I have specified overflow-y: hidden; in the CSS for the body and overflow-y:scroll; in the CSS for the element that I want to scroll. In this case, there is no scroll-bar for the body and the scrollbar is drawn for the element I want to scroll but this scrollbar is disabled and will not function. The element I want to scroll occupies the bottom 3/4 of the viewport. If I specify nothing, I get a scrollbar for the body that works but this means that all the body content scrolls. I want to keep the content of the first several elements in the body visible while the one element that contains the text that I am displaying becomes scrollable. Any suggestions on how to proceed? Any solution should work cross-browser and not require third-party code. I would prefer a solution that does not require javascript.

It would be helpful if you added your code to the question, so we have something to start from and reproduce your findings without having to reinvent the code. You can edit it, and in the editor use the <> button to add the code.

It may take quite a while to build and test a code abstract that is targeted to this issue only. Currently, the code is several 1000 lines.

The answer is simple. Just remove the overflow-y:hidden CSS from the body.
